# Metadata API - AnalyticsSettings - enable​Report​Hide​Xls​Export​Pref

Tags: api, metadata-api, analytics

I call Metadata API - [AnalyticsSettings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_analyticssettings.htm) - to check the key: enable​Report​Hide​Xls​Export​Pref.
For some reason, When I changed to value in the UI checkbox, it doesn't influence the API value.

Can anyone assume what's the issue?

[image]

Comment: Did you click Save?

Comment: Yes, I did click save.